# Restore corrupted eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

So the other day while I was programming the light went off, and now the code recommendations doesn't seem to work, and I get the following message:

> ```
> 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp.javaCompletionProposalComputer.intelligent'
> from 'org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp' plugin did not complete
> normally. Unable to instantiate the extension
> ```

I think something got corrupted, so what should I do?
Is there any way to check for files that need to be restored or something?

**Edit:**

I tried uninstalling the plugins to reinstall them later and hope everything would be fixed, but it didn't recognize I uninstalled through the assistant, so had to remove them manually from plugin folder. 
Then when reinstalling got the following message:

> ```
> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Error Reports Database".
> Error reading class bytes: com.google.common.io.Files
> ```

That error doesn't even come in a Google search so every step I take I'm more lost than I was before.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Simple, really. You just restore that plugin directory from your regular backup archives ;)  Everyone does regular backups... right?

Comment: Everyone smart enough :P